# How to reduce the android build size in unity 2017 p3

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk

I am currently using Unity 2013 p3. The problem is, when I build my project in android, the app apk size is about 29mb. And the installed app size in android is about 76mb.
Once the size was very huge, but after searching unity forums, as mentioned [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-reduce-the-android-app-build-size.438119/#post-2844384), I altered the configuration settings under Project setting -> player, and changed the device filter to ARMv7. The size has been considerably reduced then. It resulted in the above mentioned metrics which is yet too large.
I tried reducing the size by compressing images that are used in the project, by using the image compression option available in unity as mentioned [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html). The apk size is reduced somewhat, but the image quality became low comparatively.
Now I don't know any other way to reduce app size without affecting the quality. Can anyone help me with this issue?? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use compressed sounds, low poly models, set image quality to normal. Don't use  unnecessary references to prefabs. Hope this will work for you!